# Bits in XMAS Scan

Tags: tcp, packet, packet-capture

I've seen conflicting data for exactly which flags are set in an xmas packet. nmap and other packet tools use PUF flags. However, I also see documentation that states *all* flags are set; and that the PUF flags are used for certain implementations but, by definition, an xmas has all flags set.

Even http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_packet is a bit confusing in that it alludes to all flags set but then goes on to talk about what happens when the SYN flag is omitted which would not be all flags:

> "Some stateless firewalls only check
>   against security policy those packets
>   which have the SYN flag set (that is,
>   packets that initiate connection
>   according to the standards). Since
>   Christmas tree scan packets do not
>   have the SYN flag turned on, they can
>   pass through these simple systems and
>   reach the target host."

I know the distinction is a bit meaningless because either way you're essentially sending junk combinations of bits that wouldn't normally be used in a TCP/IP stream. However, I'd like to know whether an xmas packet has all bits or just the PUF bits (or either, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'When **I** use a word,' Humpty Dumpty
>   said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it
>   means just what I choose it to mean —
>   neither more nor less.'

Such is the case with "xmas packets".  There *is* no authoritative definition - it means whatever the person using the term chooses it to mean.